# Changing the height of a html div down to top without using transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to do tank animation, where according to the liquid level, the height of the tank(image) changes. For this I have written HTML code as below:

```
<div>
<img id='T1' style="height:0px;position:absolute">
</div>
```

Now I am obtaining the level information from database using ajax and trying to change the height of the image according to the value of the level parameter using JavaScript.

```
  var level=response;
 document.getElementById('T1').height=level."px";
```

This is changing the height from top to down, but I want down to top. 
Inverting the div using transform is not working. Also transition is not working as transition-time cannot be specified in this case.
Please provide me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the image `absolute` to the bottom of the container with `bottom: 0` so that it always starts at the bottom and extends from there.

To demonstrate:

```js
var level=14;
document.getElementById('T1').style.height = level+"px";

var changeLevel = function() {
    var level = document.getElementById('level').value;
    document.getElementById('T1').style.height = level+"px";
}
```

```css
div {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#T1 {
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #909;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="level" type="text" placeholder="Level" />
<input type="button" value="Change Level" onclick="changeLevel()"/>

<div>
    <div id='T1'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add following CSS for this

```
#t1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

or

```
<div>
    <img id='T1' style="height:0px;position:absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to figure out what you are trying to do. Maybe a link would help. Only thing I could see is style.height is written incorrectly.

```
document.getElementById("T1").style.height = level + "px";
```